# Caching Query Results in SQL Server Asyncronuosly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a complex SQL query which has calculating prices, discounts, quotas, places, dates, availability of rooms etc.

When a visitor search for a room, by dates, persons, places etc. on first time,
I tried returned a first page result as quickly as possible.

In first page I just analyze top 20 facilities prices, quotas, discounts etc.

Now I want to cache all list in a cache table for pagination and filtering, when first page is prepared.

My SPs are;

```
GetResultsPage:
```

This SP return page results from cache table if there is cache, or return first page if there is no cache.

```
CreateCache
```

This SP calculate and insert a full list of result into cache table with a `CacheId`

Currently I am calling `CreateCache` from client service after first page results returned.

I know, I can create a background job from C# or send a parallel request from client when is first request. But if 2 or 3 visitor search with the same parameters at the same time, there have been same conflicts. Because cache list based on search parameter. It is not personal.

I am thinking to create an SQL Agent job, which can manage cache list. The process is like below.

1- Request come to ´GetResultsPage´

2- If there is a cache and cache time NOT exceed 30 minutes, results returned from cache table

3- If there is a cache and cache time exceed 30 minutes, results returned first page

4- If there is no cache or cache required to recreated I should call `CreateCache` asyncronuosuly with parameters.

5- When `CreateCache` is running, another `CreateCache` should NOT be run with same parameters.

I need some suggestion about my strategy and hear some experience about **SQL Agent jobs** Is there any negative effect on performance.

Also If there will be a job example which can run `CreateCache` SP with prameters and prevent multiple calling I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think that you need any of this?  SQL Server already does a massive amount of caching for you on it's own.

Comment: Because, I want to return first page as fast as possible. If I calculate all result on first page request. It will take long time. After first page, client can select price order, or filter by some categories, amenities etc. Also I tested, caching on a table return 5 times faster from SQL own cache. Because there are lots of logical calculataion.

Answer (score 0):

Without reading all details, I'll address only this part:

> 5- When `CreateCache` is running, another `CreateCache` should NOT be run
>   with same parameters.

This is easy to achieve with [`sp_getapplock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CreateCache]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Param1 int
    ,@Param2 int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY
        DECLARE @VarResource nvarchar(255) = 'CreateCache';
        SET @VarResource = @VarResource + '_' + CAST(@Param1 AS nvarchar(255));
        SET @VarResource = @VarResource + '_' + CAST(@Param2 AS nvarchar(255));

        DECLARE @VarLockResult int;
        EXEC @VarLockResult = sp_getapplock
            @Resource = @VarResource,
            @LockMode = 'Exclusive',
            @LockOwner = 'Transaction',
            @LockTimeout = 1, -- play with timeout
            @DbPrincipal = 'public';

        IF @VarLockResult >= 0
        BEGIN
            -- Acquired the lock
            -- Populate the cache

        END ELSE BEGIN
            -- do nothing, because there is another instance running already
        END;

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
    END CATCH;
END
```

`@Resource` name consists of parameter values, so the second attempt to call this procedure with the same set of parameters would not obtain the lock.
If you have a lot of parameters, that would not fit into 255 characters, you can calculate a hash (see `HASHBYTES`).